# Unexpected segfault when working with raw pointers

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault, raw-pointer

Initially I wrote a Heap implementation in Rust, but I was getting strange segfaults, so I narrowed down the code to this example, which reproduces the behavior.

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;

pub struct Node<T: Ord + Debug> {
    pub value: *const T,
}

pub struct MaxHeap<T: Ord + Debug> {
    pub root: *const Node<T>,
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> MaxHeap<T> {
    pub fn push(&mut self, value: *const T) {
        self.root = &mut Node { value: value };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 124i64;
    let b = 124i64;
    let c = 1i64;

    let mut heap = MaxHeap {
        root: &mut Node { value: &a },
    };
    heap.push(&b);

    println!("{:?}", &c);
    unsafe {
        println!("{:?}", *(*heap.root).value);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e932311abd16bf16fec946ac4456b15).

The result I get from this is:

```
1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The interesting thing (to me) is that if I remove the print of `c`, there is no segfault and the correct value is printed for the heap root.

```
124
```

I expect that anything happening with `c` can't affect `heap`, but it does. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a use-after-free. In `push()`, you assign a temporary to `self.root`. The temporary's lifetime is finished of the statement and you're pointing to freed memory. Any further use will cause undefined behavior.

Miri reports it (Tools->Miri in the playground):

```
error: Undefined Behavior: pointer to alloc1786 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
  --> src/main.rs:29:26
   |
29 |         println!("{:?}", *(*heap.root).value);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pointer to alloc1786 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
   |
   = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
   = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information
           
   = note: inside `main` at src/main.rs:29:26
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

note: some details are omitted, run with `MIRIFLAGS=-Zmiri-backtrace=full` for a verbose backtrace
```

Since you've got UB, the program can do anything, and any change may affect what it does, even if it seems unrelated.

Comment: But what does the print of `c` have to do with all this? Other than that your explanation seems to point to the core problem, thanks!

Comment: @ВалентинСтайков If you're asking "how is it allowed by the language to do that", then the answer is "since you have UB all belts are off". If the question is "why does this happen _in this case_", you can analyze the resulting assembly/LLVM IR. I guess the formatting machinery of the `println!()` introduces new variables and they cause the stack to be organized differently, and because the pointer points to a free stack frame it may affect the result of dereferencing it.